# I need to compute the integral $\int _0^s\:x^2$ using Riemann sums.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I need to compute the integral $\int _0^s\:x^2$  using Riemann sums.

a) Consider the function $y=x^2$  on the interval [0, s] and divide it into n equal intervals. Each of these subintervals has length $\frac{s}{n}$.

b) Find the sum $U_n$ of all rectangles below the function $y=x^2$

$$U_n=\frac{s}{n}\left(0^3+\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)^3+\left(2\frac{s}{n}\right)^3+...+\left(n-1\right)\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)^3\right)= \frac{s^3}{n^3}\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:k^3$$

c) Now find the sum $O_n$ of all rectangles above the function $y=x^2$

$$O_n=\frac{s^3}{n^3}\left(1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3\right)=\frac{s^3}{n^3}\sum _{t=1}^nk^3$$

d) Take the limits to show that:
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(U_n\right)=\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(O_n\right)$$

So My answer is:

$$U_n=\frac{s^3}{n^3}\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}\:k^3=\frac{s^3}{n^3}((\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{6})-n^3$$

Therefore $U_n=\frac{s^3}{n^3}=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{s^3}{3}+\frac{s^3}{2n}-\frac{s^3}{n}\right)=\frac{s^3}{3}$

Is it correct? I'd appreciate some guide and feedback if I am wrong.

Comment: Isn’t $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^3 = n^2(n+1)^2/4$?

Comment: why is it over 4?

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/

Answer (score 1):

*First a comment. If you assume that $x \mapsto x^2$ is Riemann integrable, you don't need to compute both upper and lower Riemann sums and verify that those are equal. This would be required to prove the Riemann integrability.*

Now regarding the computation itself. You have

$$U_n=\frac{s}{n}\left(0^2+\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)^2+\left(2\frac{s}{n}\right)^2+...+\left(n-1\right)\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)^2\right)= \frac{s^3}{n^3}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k^2.$$

**The power is $2$ and not $3$ as you're integrating $x \mapsto x^2$**.

Using

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k^2 = \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}$$ and taking the limit you get the right answer $$\int_0^s x^2 \ dx = \frac{s^3}{3}.$$